# Power Automate - using variables in adaptive cards

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

I'm trying to build a flow that operates in Teams that does the following:

- A user posts a new message to a channel
- The flow reads the message and gathers some variables (userId, messageBody, etc.)
- The flow bot posts an adaptive card to gather more information from the user.

I am able to insert variables from higher up in the flow into the adaptive card, but I'm having a hard time using them with "$when" conditions in the card. Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "data": {
    "postContainsLink": "@{variables('postContainsLink')}",
    "testNum": "@{variables('testNum')}",
    "otherTestNum": "100"
  },
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "size": "Medium",
      "weight": "Bolder",
      "text": "@{variables('messageBody')}",
      "$when": "${postContainsLink == true}"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "size": "Medium",
      "weight": "Bolder",
      "text": "If you're seeing this text block, something went wrong. Bummer.",
      "$when": "${testNum < 100}"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "size": "Medium",
      "weight": "Bolder",
      "text": "If you're seeing this text block, something else went wrong. Bummer.",
      "$when": "${otherTestNum < 50}"
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.2"
}
```

None of the "$when" values are preventing any of these textblocks from appearing. But the first one is able to display the message body successfully.

How can I use variables to show or hide text blocks within the adaptive card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you please try [this sample](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Action.ToggleVisibility.html). It explains how to hide/show the text blocks.